# Weird "1103 Incorrect table name" error

Tags: database, collection, error, sql, product-collection

The code:

```
    public function testAction(){
        $Collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $Collection->getSelect()->join(array('t2' => 'SELECT product_id FROM sales_flat_quote_item GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY SUM(qty) DESC;'), 'e.entity_id = t2.product_id', 't2.product_id');

        foreach($Collection as $c){
            var_dump($c);
        }
    }
```

Here is the [error trace](http://pastebin.com/pfgMG2TX).

Incorrect table name `sales_flat_quote_item`?

What's the problem here? I'm tempted to manually create the whole query and be done with it.. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the grouping part but you can join the product collection with the sales item collection like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->joinTable(
    array('t2'=>'sales/quote_item'),
    'product_id = entity_id',
    array('product_id')
);
```

I think you can continue on this.

**[EDIT] - unrelated to the question but a possible solution to the problem**
You can get the bestsellers like this.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/report_bestsellers_collection')
        ->setModel('catalog/product')
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())//if you want the bestsellers for a specific store view. if you want global values remove this
        ->setPageSize(5)//set here the number of products you want returned - skip this and the next line if you want all the products but this may lead to performance issues.
        ->setCurPage(1);
```

**[second degree edit]**
If you print the collection select in your case using `$collection->getSelect()` you will see something like this:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS `status`, 
    `e`.`entity_id`, 
    `e`.`type_id`, 
    `e`.`attribute_set_id`, 
    `t2`.`product_id` 
FROM 
    `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` 
INNER JOIN 
    `(SELECT product_id FROM sales_flat_quote_item GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY SUM(qty) DESC)` AS `t2`
ON e.entity_id = t2.product_id
```

Notice the quote mark (`) after the `INNER JOIN`. There it should be a table name. Instead you have a full select. This is not correct syntactically...hence the error.

Comment: Thanks! No chance on the grouping and ordering?

Comment: You can try to sort and group using `$collection->getSelect()->order('...')` and `$collection->getSelect()->group('...')` but I don't know exactly what you should put there.

Comment: My goal is to order by quantity soled, if that helps..

Comment: @Dror. Then why don't you ask the right question. See my edit to the answer. Maybe it fits your needs.

Comment: I set this answer as correct because, practically, it solves my problem. But It is still not clear why I get that error.. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Dror. I have an idea why. See my "second degree" edit. I added it to the answer because it's easier to format than in a comment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13248/discussion-between-dror-and-marius)